# Update a Table Variable Where Not Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

```
UPDATE 
    @Customer
SET 
    ValidaitonAction = 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM DMScustomerupload WHERE AccountNumber = @Customer.AccountNumber)
```

Where `@Customer` is a TABLE variable:

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE ( ID int,
                        ValidaitonAction int,
                        ... other columns))
```

On the last line, I get

> Must declare scalar variable @Customer

Comment: Please show where you `DECLARE @Customer`

Comment: Use an alias for the table variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a table alias:

```
UPDATE c
    SET ValidationAction = 1
    FROM @Customer c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DMScustomerupload cu WHERE cu.AccountNumber = c.AccountNumber);
```

SQL Server automatically interprets anything that starts with a `@` as a variable (of some sort).  Table aliases are a different thing, so it doesn't find a match.

Comment: Thanks! Knew I needed an alias, just wasn't sure how to declare it.

Comment: I'm getting `invalid column name ValidationAction` on the SET line.  (I edited the OP to show the table declaration)

Comment: /\ ignore. Typo.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston `SET C.ValidationAction = 1`